# Latest android no longer sends UDP broadcast packets

Tags: android, sockets, udp, cordova-plugins

So we have been running the following code on android (Samsung Note 4) and iOS with out trouble until the latest phones started coming out with android 7+ (Samsung S8, OnePlus3T).  We would send out our broadcast to identify other systems that would respond to this message.  Now we find that UDP is blocked on the phone.

We have used Evothings to test that UDP is blocked.  Programmatically I don't think I am missing anything to make this work.

We have noticed a change with the way WiFi works on android. If the WiFi connection doesn't have internet, the system seems to behave differently.

```
    chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function (networkIfaceArray) {
         for (var i = 0; i < networkIfaceArray.length; i++) {
                var iface = networkIfaceArray[i];
                if (iface.prefixLength < 32) {
                    addr_array = parseIP(iface.address);
                    mask = 32 - iface.prefixLength;
                    mask = Math.pow(2, mask) - 1;
                    pointer = 3;
                    while (mask > 255) {
                        addr_array[pointer++] = 255;
                        mask -= 255;
                    }
                    addr_array[pointer] = mask;
                    udp_sock.send(app.socketId, message,
                    addr_array.join("."), 5000, function (sendInfo) {
                        //check for response
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

We have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43257227/1280057) where they suggest different ports.  Most of the posts here are older than version 7 and so don't address our problem.

Again, it still works with the older versions of android and iOS.  If you have come across this problem please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the setBroadcast() function.  Old versions of the cordova plugin did not have it implemented, see https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp/issues/7, so you may have to check if it is defined before using it.  Possibly the Evothings app uses an older version of the cordova plugin.  Maybe the newer Android devices default the broadcast option off, so calling setBroadcast() should allow it to work.

```
// Set Broadcast (if available)
if (chrome.sockets.udp.setBroadcast != undefined) {
   chrome.sockets.udp.setBroadcast(app.socketId, true, function (result) {
      if (result < 0) {
       console.log("setBroadcast failed");
      }
      else {
       console.log("setBroadcast worked");
      }
   });
}
```